# Searching and moving files

Tags: linux

I have 9000+ XML files in a folder. I'm searching for those that contains a certain word then copy them to a certain location. I'm using the terminal:-

```
grep -r "the word I'm searching"
```

It's working but I'm looking for a better and faster way if anybody has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and efficient way:

```
find . -name '*.xml' | xargs grep -l 'You search string' \
| xargs mv -t your_target_directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single line using the following code

```
mv `ls | grep 'the word you are searching for' -rl` directoryname/
```

This works only if your directory contains only xml file.

Comment: I'm getting this error **mv: missing destination file operand after 'folder_specified'**

Comment: Add a slash after the directory name.

Comment: it didn't work, however you were almost on point. I had to add ' -rl ' after grep.

Comment: I don't know who did that because I didn't.